# How to get property name desending order in every record using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

Considering the following records:

```
                    _______________________
Id      S1      S2  |   S3      S4      S5 |
--------------------|----------------------|
1       5       7   |   8       2       5  |    
2       22      24  |   7       9       10 |
3       19      17  |   8       2       3  |
4       7       8   |   9       1       0  |
5       15      1   |   7       9       10 |
                    ________________________
```

I want to get top 2 Property Name according to descending order within S3, S4, S5 column- from each record-  similar to these records:

```
Id      1st Top     2nd Top
---------------------------
1       S3 (8)      S5 (5)  
2       S5 (10)     S4 (9) 
3       S3 (8)      S5 (3)
4       S3 (9)      S4 (1)
5       S5 (10)     S4 (9)
```

How I can do this using linq?

Note: S3/S4/S5 are integer type.

I want top 2 property name in string value.

Comment: Few doubts: `1`: What is the type of variable that holds this data? is that in database? `2`: How the 2nd top and 1st top are calculated? `3`: what is the type that you are expecting. One general instruction *Please describe about your issues, sample inputs, expected output etc., when you come up with your next question*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to fix your data like this:

```
var data = records.Select(r=>new {Id=r.Id,Field="S1",Value=r.S1})
  .Concat(records.Select(r=>new {Id=r.Id,Field="S2",Value=r.S2}))
  .Concat(records.Select(r=>new {Id=r.Id,Field="S3",Value=r.S3}))
  .Concat(records.Select(r=>new {Id=r.Id,Field="S4",Value=r.S4}))
  .Concat(records.Select(r=>new {Id=r.Id,Field="S5",Value=r.S5}));
```

Then you can manipulate it (although a simple group by is probably just better):

```
var results = data
  .Where(d=>d.Field == "S3" || d.Field == "S4" || d.Field == "S5")
  .GroupBy(d=>d.Id)
  .Select(grp=>new {
    Id, 
    First = d.OrderByDescending(f=>f.Value).First(),
    Second = d.OrderByDescending(f=>f.Value).Skip(1).First()
  });
```

This is sort of the long way to do this, but it's the most generic.  You don't really need to concat the s1/s2 at all, but I left them there just because other queries you may want to make on this data may require them.

Printing them out:

```
foreach(var rec in data.OrderBy(r=>r.Id))
{
  Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} ({2}) {3} ({4}), 
    rec.Id, rec.First.Field, rec.First.Value, rec.Second.Field, rec.Second.Value);
}
```

Or you could do it like this:

```
var data = records.Select(r=>new {Id=r.Id,Field="S3",Value=r.S3})
  .Concat(records.Select(r=>new {Id=r.Id,Field="S4",Value=r.S4}))
  .Concat(records.Select(r=>new {Id=r.Id,Field="S5",Value=r.S5}));

foreach(var rec in data
  .GroupBy(z=>z.Id)
  .OrderBy(z=>z.Id))
{
  Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} ({2}) {3} ({4}), 
    rec.Key, 
    rec.OrderByDescending(f=>f.Value).First().Field,
    rec.OrderByDescending(f=>f.Value).First().Value,
    rec.OrderByDescending(f=>f.Value).Skip(1).First().Field,
    rec.OrderByDescending(f=>f.Value).Skip(1).First().Value);
}
```

Or you could generate the normalized data like this if it makes more sense to you:

```
var data = records.Select(r=> new {
  Id=r.Id,
  Values=new[]{
    new {Field="S3",Value=r.S3},
    new {Field="S4",Value=r.S4},
    new {Field="S5",Value=r.S5}}});
```